# pytorch_jni.dll: The specified procedure could not be found -> Module.load function when loading Pytorch model in Kotlin/Java. Please fix this

Tags: android, kotlin, dll, pytorch, java-native-interface

I have a pytorch model that I want to run in android. I have serialized it using torch.jit.trace. When I load it using this line `Module module = Module.load("model.pt");`, I get this error. Every line in the error is pointing to this function.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\pytorch_jni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:287)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2427)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.SystemDelegate.loadLibrary(SystemDelegate.java:24)
    at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:52)
    at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:30)
    at org.pytorch.NativePeer.<clinit>(NativePeer.java:10)
    at org.pytorch.Module.load(Module.java:28)
    at org.pytorch.Module.load(Module.java:38)
    at com.example.pytorch_app.Temp.main(Temp.java:28)
```

These are the dependencies

```
implementation 'org.pytorch:pytorch_android:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5+'
```

I have tried changing the version in dependencies, downgrading/upgrading pytorch, tried both Java and Kotlin, but I'm getting the same error.